# Esscher transform of unimodal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with distribution function $F_X$, and suppose $F_X$ is unimodal. (Here, unimodal is taken to mean that the density function of $X$ is monotone increasing (resp. decreasing) for all $x<x^*$ (resp. $x >x^*$), where $x^*$ is the argmax of the density function.)

The [Esscher transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esscher_transform) of $X$ can be defined as
\begin{align*}
    dF_X^{(t)}(x) := \frac{e^{t x} dF_X(x)}{\mathbb{E}_X[e^{t X}]} = \exp \left(tx - K_X(t) \right)  dF_X(x) , \qquad t\in \mathcal{T},
\end{align*}
with $\mathcal{T} = \{t \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{E}_X[e^{t X}] < \infty  \}$, and where $K_X$ is the cumulant generating function.

Does it follow that the transformed distribution function, $F_X^{(t)}$, is also unimodal in $x$? If so, how does one go about showing this?

If this is not possible, can we impose further constraints to get the desired result, ex. $F_X$ is a unimodal member of the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)?

Comment: For every $t$, whether $F_X(x)^t$ is unimodal in $x$. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the moment generating function is well defined, is the transformed density $dF_X^{(t)}(x)$ unimodal in $x$.